# Custom Domain Mail in Android

Tags: android, email

Hello friends i want configure mail settings in android .. 
when i search it on internet , 
i was just able to send only via g-mail only , 
how can i send mail in custom domain 
e,g : someone@example.com
If this is possible please reply at your earliest

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText recipient,subject,body;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recipient = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.receiptent);
        subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);
        body = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body); 

        Button sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendEmail);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {
             sendEmail();
             recipient.setText("");
             subject.setText("");
             body.setText("");
           }
     });

    }

    protected void sendEmail() {

        String[] recipients = {recipient.getText().toString()};
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        email.setType("message/rfc822");

        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.getText().toString());
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body.getText().toString());

        try {
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an email client from..."));

        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No email client installed.",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Action_send intent the user chooses how to send the mail. So if you only have g-mail configured on your test device you will only be able to send via g-mail.

Setting up a mail app, which has an action_send intent-filter, with an account like someone@example.com will add this mail app to the options of the intent.

If you want to choose the account and send the mail programmatically, then i guess you would have to use an API like JavaMail.

see

- [Send auto email programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668871/send-auto-email-programmatically)
- [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)
- [Android : email sending without google signing in (Automatically sending mails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675771/android-email-sending-without-google-signing-in-automatically-sending-mails?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

1.i want configure mail settings in android, e,g : someone@example.com if this is possible  please reply at your earliest.

```
YES,this is possible in android.you can user any proxy server like abc@anyDomain.com.
```

//you can use the below code to send email from you android client.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
public class EMailSender {
public EMailSender(String host, final String from, final String pass, String to, String      sub, String mess) throws Exception {
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
return new PasswordAuthentication(from, pass);
}};
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
message.setSubject(sub);
message.setText(mess);
Transport.send(message);
}

public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
if(arg.length == 5) {
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String temp = "", subject;
System.out.print("Enter subject: ");
subject = br.readLine();
System.out.println("Enter the message (end it with a . on a single line):");
while((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
if(temp.equals("."))
break;
message.append(temp+"\n");
}
System.out.println("Sending message...");
new EMailSender(arg[0], arg[1], arg[2], arg[3], subject, message.toString());
System.out.println("Sent the message.");
  }
 else System.err.println("Usage:\njava SendTextMail <host> <port> <from> <pass> <to>");
}
}
```

make a seprate class and put all this code in taht class.now you have to call the
constructor of this class by passing required parameters. and can the easily send mail to **anyone from any server.**

Comment: i'm not getting you , please send me , full project in android